# Im making a skypebot and my resolver wont work

Tags: c#, vb.net, skype

I am making a skype bot, using the Skype4COMLib but i cannot get my resolver to work!

```
Private Sub oSkype_MessageStatus(pMessage As ChatMessage, Status As TChatMessageStatus) Handles oSkype.MessageStatus
    If Status = TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived Or Status = TChatMessageStatus.cmsSent Then
        Dim Msg As String = pMessage.Body
        Dim c As Chat = pMessage.Chat
        If Msg.StartsWith("~~~~~~~~~ SDMbae ~~~~~~~~~" + vbNewLine + "SDMbae: Resolving user ") Then
            Try

                Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("My API key is here" + Msg.Split(" ")(5))
                Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
                Dim source As String = New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream).ReadToEnd
                pMessage.Body = "~~~~~~~~~ SDMbae ~~~~~~~~~" + vbNewLine + "SDMbae: IP for " + Msg.Split(" ")(5) + " is: " + source.Split(",")(0) + vbNewLine + "SDMbae: Other IPs are " + source.Remove(0, source.Split(",")(0).Length + 1).Split("|")(0).Replace(",", " and ") + vbNewLine + "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
            Catch ex As Exception
                pMessage.Body = "~~~~~~~~~ SDMbae ~~~~~~~~~" + vbNewLine + "SDMbae: Error resolving user " + Msg.Split(" ")(5) + vbNewLine + "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
            End Try
        End If
```

can anyone help me???

Comment: Any help? I really need some help!

Comment: Do you get an error? What exactly do you want this code to do? Please be more clear with your question. Maybee try and put a breakpoint and see what happens.